# What's the recommended way to start using types from a returned DataRow in C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

When looping through a DataRow and encountering types such as

```
DataRow dr;
dr["someString"]
dr["someInteger"]
dr["somedata"]
```

What's the best way to get them into their corresponding data types?  dr["foo"] is just a generic object.

Also, are these able to be easily converted to nullable types?  dr["someInteger"] could be null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When reading from a DataRow, your biggest enemy is a null value. In a `DataRow`, when a value is null, it is not equals to null: It is equals to `DBNull.Value`.

```
if(DBNull.Value == null)
{
   // Will never happen
}
```

Unless you know that your field cannot be null, it is not safe to cast. For example, the following example will fail if the data is DBNull:

```
string name = (string)dr["Name"];
```

If you can use the LINQ extensions, you can include the reference `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and the namespace `System.Data` and call

```
string name = dr.Field<string>("Name");
```

If you cannot use LINQ, then you have to fall back to checking for null value with

```
string name = null;
if(!dr.IsNull("Name"))
    name = (string)dr["Name"];
```

Or you could code your own Field function like this:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object value)
{
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return default(T);
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```

and get your value this way:

```
string name = GetValue<string>(dr["Name"]);
```

Comment: What happens if you call int i = dr.Field<int>("someintcolumn"); and the row is null?

Comment: Field<T>() is bright enough to return default(T), so your i variable will be equals to 0 if the data is null.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use .net 3.5, then you can use the [Field extension method](http://dotnetperls.com/datarow-field) to more easily access the data if you know the type.  An example would be:

```
 string somestring= row.Field<string>("SomeString");
```

Otherwise you're stuck with casting the field to the type of the object the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

Simply casting the values to the right type should work:

```
(string) dr["someString"];
(int?) dr["someInteger"];
(byte[]) dr["somedata"];
```

Comment: Warning, `(int?) dr["someInteger"];` will fail if the value is DBNull.

Comment: Is there any benefit of casting verses calling int.Parse() for example?

Comment: Is there a shortcut to getting (int?) to work.  I'm thinking something like int?.TryParse(dr["some"]) ? (int?)dr["some"] : null

Comment: int.Parse only accepts a string as parameter, so that won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
string GetString(DataRow dr, string ColumnName)
{
    if (dr.IsNull(ColumnName)) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    return (string)dr[ColumnName];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to return an empty string instead of null here?

Comment: Maybe, but there can also be "" in column value, so you have to differentiate somehow.  It depends on how you like/need it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use "as"

```
string str = dr["someString"] as string;
```

if it's DBNull.Value (or any other object not of type string), then str will get a real "null".  Otherwise it will get the proper string value.

For value types, you can use nullable, i.e.

```
int? i = dr["someint"] as int?;
```

Again, it will get a real "null" instead of DBNull.Value.  However, with nullable types you have to remember to use .Value, i.e.

```
int x = i.Value + 5;
```

Comment: int? i = 3; 
int x = i + 5; won't work? Weird! Never knew that.