# Checking for nulls

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Sorry for such simple question.

How would I check this for nulls?

```
obj.DivisionNotes = (string)row["DivisionNotes"];
```

I'm thinking something like this.

```
obj.DivisionNotes = (string)row["DivisionNotes"]?null:"No notes";
```

Am I right.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your casting of a null will cause a problem, you can use an `as` cast along with the null coalescing operator to solve your issues..

```
obj.DivisionNotes = (row["DivisionNotes"] as string) ?? "No notes";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ISNULL function in your original T-SQL query, changing a query like this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, DivisionNotes FROM tblWHATEVER
```

to

```
SELECT ID, Name, ISNULL(DivisionNotes, 'No notes') AS 
    DivisionNotes FROM tblWHATEVER
```

I'm not saying this is better than checking for null in your code, but sometimes a simple change in your query can save you from changing your code in a bunch of different places.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why you got a minus vote for that idea. Anyway thanks for the input.

Comment: @Chin: someone figured I didn't really answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to handle nulls in a datarow. Please [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381349/whats-the-recommended-way-to-start-using-types-from-a-returned-datarow-in-c/1381451#1381451) where I explain multiple method of doing that.